# How to Reference Defined Values

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file that is attempting to reference a previously defined value, but the container of the value is null:

```
if (typeof (myNamespace) == "undefined") { myNamespace = {}; }

myNamespace.myClass = {
    myConstants: {
        value: "someValue",
    },

    something : {
        values: [myNamespace.myClass.myConstants.value] // Errors here
    }
};
```

I thought JavaScript executed in a top down manner, so the `myNamespace.myClass.myConstants.value` should be already be defined when the `something.values[]` is getting populated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the point your expression `myNamespace.myClass.myConstants.value` is evaluated, the value of `myNamespace.myClass` is still `undefined`. Until the whole object initializer expression is evaluated, the assignment doesn't happen.

The upshot of this is that there's no way to make internal cross-references from inside an object initializer expression. You have to split it out into a separate assignment.

```
myNamespace.myClass = {
    myConstants: {
        value: "someValue",
    },

    something : {
        values: []
    }
};

myNamespace.myClass.something.values.push(myNamespace.myClass.myConstants.value);
```

Comment: So I'll have to call a function to populate the values then if I want to reference it?

Comment: @Daryl you don't have to call a function, but you do need something separate from the object initializer.